# Run call columns data of another dataframe, row by row

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my First dataframe,

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(9*9, 1, 0.5), ncol=9, nrow =9))
colnames(df1) <- paste(rep(c("a","b","c"), each=3), rep(c(1,2,3), 3), sep = "")
set.seed(11)
```

This is my Second dataframe,

```
factor.1 <- paste(rep(c("a","b"), each=3), rep(c(1,2,3), 2), sep = "")
factor.2 <- rep(paste(rep("c", 3), c(1,2,3), sep = ""), 2)
df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(factor.1,factor.2))
```

I want to calculate the result in each column and put it inside the second dataframe. I use dplyr

```
fun1 <- function(x){sum(ds1[, x])}
df2%>% mutate(value = fun1(factor.1))
```

But what I get is this,

```
  factor.1 factor.2    value
1       a1       c1       22
2       a2       c2       22
3       a3       c3       22
4       b1       c1       22
5       b2       c2       22
6       b3       c3       22
```

But What I want is this,

```
   factor.1 factor.2    value
  1       a1       c1       4
  2       a2       c2       4
  3       a3       c3       4
  4       b1       c1       1
  5       b2       c2       4
  6       b3       c3       5
```

Comment: Not clear.  Is the 'value' based on the sum of each corresponding pair of columns? i.e. `do.call(rbind, Map(function(x,y) colSums(df1[c(x,y)]), as.character(df2$factor.1), as.character(df2$factor.2)))`

Comment: Also, where is `temp_p.value.data` defined  or may be `unlist(Map(function(x,y) sum(colSums(df1[c(x,y)])), as.character(df2$factor.1), as.character(df2$factor.2)))`

Comment: `df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(temp_factor.1,temp_factor.2))` , where is `temp_factor.1`, do you mean `factor.1`?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake when trying to simplify the code. I have modified it.

Comment: what is value column ? how is it calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
df2 %>% mutate(value = sapply(factor.1, fun1) )
```